# Can I have text over an image in joomla?

Tags: image, text, joomla, background, content-management-system

So I want to make the texts in joomla articles have an individual background images.  Let's say I have an ellipsis image (like shown below) and I want every word on that article have the ellipsis image behind their text.

[image: ellipsis]

How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you should work with CSS `class` and `span` tags:

1. Define a new css class with your background-image and add the class to your default `.css` file or custom file: eg. `.ellipsis {background: url(img_flwr.gif; background-repeat: no-repeat)}`. Make sure you are using the correct path in your URL
2. Put `span` tags around the words and use the `class`:  `<span class="ellipsis>word</span>`.

This should work.